# Joining the equivalent numbers from two different arrays into one array

Tags: java, arrays, duplicates

I have to create two arrays with ten random values between 0 and 20. With those arrays create two more arrays:

- `arrayReps` contains the numbers that match between the two arrays.  For example with arrays of 3 values: `[3, 2, 4]`, `[4, 5, 2]` then `arrayReps = [2, 4]` (order doesnt matter)
- `arrayUniq` contains the unique values of each of the original arrays. From the previous example, `arrayUniq = [3, 5]`.

I already created the two random arrays, but i am having trouble on the arrayReps and arrayUniq, can you help me out? My Code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class P03ArraysExtractUniqsAndReps {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random number = new Random();
        int a = 0;
        int[] randomArray1;
        randomArray1 = new int[10];
        int[] randomArray2;
        randomArray2 = new int[10];
        int[] arrayUniq;
        int[] arrayReps;
        //int[] arrayUniq = new int[10];
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            randomArray1[i] = number.nextInt(20);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            randomArray2[i] = number.nextInt(20);
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(randomArray1));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(randomArray2));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific in what you are having trouble with.  What aspects of populating the `unique` and `duplicate` arrays are you struggling with?  Detecting duplicates?  Actually putting the elements into the arrays?

Comment: The answer to your only explicit question here is, of course, yes.  But that is probably not all you want to know.

Comment: You might want to use an inner loop.

Comment: Having trouble? Of course, you have no code for the other 2 methods yet. Start by creating methods and adding relevant code to them..that should do it! If that doesn't work, see the help section for more info on how to create a valid question that doesn't include doing it for you: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Compare each element of `a1` with the elements of `a2`. If the match is found, store that element in `arrayReps`, else store the element in `arrayUniq`

Something like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<a1.length;i++)
{
   for(int j=0;j<a2.length;j++)
   {
      if(a1[i]==a2[j])
           //add the element in arrayReps
      else
           //add the element in arrayUniq
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, grab one or both as you wish:

**Duplicates** O(n+m)

```
public static int[] getDuplicates(int[] array1, int[] array2) {
    HashSet<Integer> duplicates = new HashSet<>(); 
    HashSet<Integer> uniques = new HashSet<>(); 
    for(int i : array1) {
        if (!uniques.add(i)) {
            duplicates.add(i);
        } 
    }
    for(int j : array2) {
        if (!uniques.add(j)) {
            duplicates.add(j);
        } 
    }
    return duplicates.stream().mapToInt(i->i).toArray();
}
```

---

**Uniques** O(n+m)

```
public static int[] getUniques(int[] array1, int[] array2) {
    HashSet<Integer> uniques = new HashSet<>();
    for(int i : array1) {
        uniques.add(i);
    }
    for (int j : array2) {
        uniques.add(j);
    }
    return uniques.stream().mapToInt(i->i).toArray();
}
```

---

**All at once** O(n+m)

In case you don't want to use two methods, just put the body of `getDuplicates(..)` method (it calculates both of duplicates and uniques) to your `main(..)` one.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] array1 = {1,2,5,6,8,9,1};
    int[] array2 = {3,4,5,6,0};

    HashSet<Integer> setDuplicates = new HashSet<>(); 
    HashSet<Integer> setUniques = new HashSet<>(); 
    for (int i : array1) {
        if (!setUniques.add(i)) {
            setDuplicates.add(i);
        } 
    }
    for (int j : array2) {
        if (!setUniques.add(j)) {
            setDuplicates.add(j);
        } 
    }

    int[] duplicates = setDuplicates.stream().mapToInt(i->i).toArray();
    int[] uniques = setUniques.stream().mapToInt(i->i).toArray();

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(duplicates));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(uniques));
}
```

---

All methods will give you the same output:

```
Duplicates: [1, 5, 6]
Uniques: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use bucket sort which is the most efficient and the conditions of bucketSort are met: the max and min values are known.

```
    int[] bucketSortArray = new int[20];
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        bucketSortArray[randomArray1[i]]++;
        bucketSortArray[randomArray2[i]]++;
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bucketSortArray));
```

if `bucketSortArray[15]==1,` than 15 is unique.
if `bucketSortArray[20]>1,` than 20 is in Reps.
if it's 0, ignore.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of doing it.

Compare the first list of numbers against the second list, then whatever is left in the second list must also be unique.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class UniqueArray {
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int[] list1 = {0,4,6,2,8,9};
    int[] list2 = {0,4,3,2,7,5};
    ArrayList<Integer> unique = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> dups = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 

    boolean isUnique = false;
    int num;

    for(int i = 0; i < list1.length; i++)
    {
        num = list1[i];
        for(int j = 0; j < list1.length; j++)
        {
            isUnique = true;
            if(list1[i] == list2[j])
            {
                isUnique = false;
                list2[j] = -1; // mark as having already been found
                break;
            }
        }
        if(isUnique)
        {
            unique.add(num);
        }
        else
        {
            dups.add(num);
        }
    }

    for(int i=0; i< list2.length; i++)
    {
        if(list2[i]!= -1)
        {
            unique.add(list2[i]);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Unique:");
    System.out.println(unique);

    System.out.println("Dups:");
    System.out.println(dups);   
}
```

}